# How are std::array's compared in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, comparison-operators, stdarray

For the below code, why is the output coming as 1?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 5> a { 10, 11, 12, 15, 14 };
    std::array<int, 5> b { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
    std::cout << (a < b);
}
```

Comment: Read some documentation to find out https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare

Comment: Try `cout << std::boolalpha << (a < b);`

Comment: `why is the output coming as 1?` what output did you expect? 1 seems right to me.

Comment: @Borgleader: OP doesn't have that intuition, hence his/her question. Maybe OP was expecting an error? Or a 0 for incomparability?

Comment: I think that's the point though @einpoklum. They didn't tell us _what_ they expected.

Comment: @einpoklum my point exactly, if i dont know why they expected that i can't explain why the intuition is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

They use the standard algorithm `std::lexicographical_compare`

From the description of the algorithm in the C++ Standard

> 3 Remarks: If two sequences have the same number of elements and their
>   corresponding elements (if any) are equivalent, then neither sequence
>   is lexicographically less than the other. If one sequence is a prefix
>   of the other, then the shorter sequence is lexicographically less than
>   the longer sequence. Otherwise, the lexicographical comparison of the
>   sequences yields the same result as the comparison of the first
>   corresponding pair of elements that are not equivalent.

The output of your example is boolean `true` that is "...the same result as the comparison of the first corresponding pair of elements that are not equivalent."

For your example the result of the comparison `(a < b)` is the result of the comparison `( a[0] < b[0] )`

Below there is a demonstrative program For example you can write such an operator for the class template std::vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
bool operator <( const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &b )
{
    return std::lexicographical_compare( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ),
                                         std::begin( b ), std::end( b ) );
}

int main() 
{
    std::array<int, 5> a { 10, 11, 12, 15, 14 };
    std::array<int, 5> b { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
              << std::lexicographical_compare( a.begin(), a.end(),
                                               b.begin(), b.end() )
              << '\n';

    std::vector<int> a1 { 10, 11, 12, 15, 14 };
    std::vector<int> b1 { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ( a1 < b1 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```